# C# File.ReadAllBytes vs std::ifstream (Windows)

Tags: c#, c++, windows

In C# and C++ reading in all bytes from a network file give massively different results. C++ is taking close to three times as long as C#

C#

```
File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
```

C++

```
std::ifstream str_in(fp, std::ifstream::binary);

int data_rem = fs_len;
int data_read = 0;

while (data_rem>0)
{
    str_in.read(buffer+ data_read, 1024*1024*1);
    data_rem -= str_in.gcount();
    data_read += str_in.gcount();
}
```

Using the C struct FILE gave the same results as C++

Comment: I hope the C++ code is only a simplified example, it looks like a buffer overflow to me.

Comment: complete code and test results added into another post

Answer (score 1):

Drilling into the [C# source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,ee8033fcb7e7a677) we can see that it is calling ReadFile from kernal32.dll, replicating the same code in C++ gives the same performance.

```
HANDLE f_handle = CreateFile(fp, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

DWORD read=0;
ReadFile(f_handle, buffer, fs_len, &read, NULL);

CloseHandle(f_handle);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I ran some further tests and have given the complete code/results below.

Test was setup by;

1. Creating an identical file for each file read on the network. FileSize ~37MB.
2. Using a C# main loop to call the SLT (std::ifstream) and then the Windows ReadFile approach in alternating fashion, for 50 files (25 files each).
3. Repeat step 2 for a number of different read sizes {KB*1, KB*4, KB*32, MB*1, MB*5}
4. Wait a 20mins to ensure caching is not affecting anything and redo step 2 and 3

All code is compile in release mode, visual studio 2015 community version.

---

C# Calling Code

```
[DllImport(DLL_NAME, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int test(string data_in, int option, int block_size);

...

string fp_template = @"N:/foo/{0}/bar ({1}).csv";

int KB = 1024;
int MB = KB * 1024;

int block_id = 0;
foreach (var block_size in new int[] {KB*1,KB*4,KB*32,MB*1,MB*5 })
{
    Console.WriteLine("BlockSize (KB): " +(block_size/1024));
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        Stopwatch sw_loop = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        ParseBlockNative.test(String.Format(fp_template,block_id, i), i % 2,block_size);
        Console.WriteLine("Option: {0} Taken: {1}", i % 2 == 0 ? "0-SLT" : "1-WIN", sw_loop.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    block_id++;
}
```

C++ IO Code

```
extern "C" int DllExport test(wchar_t* fp,int option,int block_size)
{
    int fs_len = 38441760;

    char* buffer = (char*)malloc(fs_len);

    int data_rem = fs_len;
    int data_read = 0;

    if (option==0)
    {
        std::ifstream str_in(fp, std::ifstream::binary);

        while (data_rem > 0)
        {
            str_in.read(buffer + data_read, min(block_size,data_rem));
            data_rem -= str_in.gcount();
            data_read += str_in.gcount();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        HANDLE f_handle = CreateFile(fp, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

        while (data_rem > 0)
        {
            DWORD read = 0;
            ReadFile(f_handle, buffer + data_read, min(block_size, data_rem), &read, NULL);

            data_rem -= read;
            data_read += read;
        }

        CloseHandle(f_handle);
    }

    free(buffer);

    return data_read;
}
```

---

**These test results have been superseded, please skip to the next section**

Time to read in a 37MB file from the network, averaged over 25 files per data point.

Take 1

```
+------------+------+----------+
| Block_Size | SLT  | Kernel32 |
+------------+------+----------+
| 1KB        |  957 |     1065 |
| 4KB        |  965 |      953 |
| 32KB       |  952 |      729 |
| 1MB        | 1015 |      230 |
| 5MB        |  993 |      231 |
+------------+------+----------+
```

Take 2 (same test redone 20 mins later)

```
+------------+------+----------+
| Block_Size | SLT  | Kernel32 |
+------------+------+----------+
| 1KB        | 1040 |      999 |
| 4KB        | 1077 |     1102 |
| 32KB       | 1079 |      784 |
| 1MB        | 1028 |      231 |
| 5MB        | 1035 |      201 |
+------------+------+----------+
```

---

Comments:
Changing the read size does not improve the STL results.
Kernel32 times improve slightly going from 4KB to 32KB and alot from 32KB to 1MB.

My hunch at the moment is that being a network drive the latency is very high but the bandwidth is large. A number of small requests (~4KB) is alot slower than fewer larger (~1MB) requests. The latency is much more than we would see on a regular SSD or HDD and so the penalty is more sever for more requests.
Even though I tell the STL to read in 1MB chunks the results suggest it ignores this and requests a number of 4KB reads.

---

**Update** - Unique data

The speed improvement seen in the above section for Kernel32 going from 32KB to 1MB seemed a bit unbelievable to me. I was using a unique file for each read operation but the contents were the same. I was concerned that there was some level of caching going on based on data content. I redid the above test but this time I randomly generated unique files for each read operation.

Each below data point represents the average of 25 different files with randomly generated content.

```
+------------+---------+----------+
| Block_Size |   SLT   | Kernel32 |
+------------+---------+----------+
| 1KB        |  976    |  1,101   |
| 4KB        |  1,027  |  1,011   |
| 32KB       |  969    |  768     |
| 1MB        |  981    |  530     |
| 5MB        |  1,008  |  541     |
+------------+---------+----------+
```

For completeness the time taken for C#'s File.ReadAllBytes to complete is about 585ms, close to the Kernel32 1MB times.

I redid a subset of the above test passing FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING to Kernel32, the 1MB runtime increased to about 700ms closer but still significantly better than the STL.

Comments:
It looks to me like the effects of network caching on the server end has been removed.
What I see is that C#\Kernel32 out performs the SLT. With no increase in performance seen in the SLT by increasing the read size.

Comment: You'll need to find another theory, File.ReadAllBytes() also uses a 4KB buffer.  You also need to run the test in reverse so you can eliminate/detect file system caching effects.  The most likely cause of the speed difference.

Comment: Our network does do caching and I could see its effects in initial testing. I corrected for this in my above testing by creating a unique file for every read. ie I averaged over 25 files for 5 different block sizes for both SLT and Kerel32, so I had 25*5*2 different (but equal) files on the network. No file was read twice so reversing the order would do nothing. I do agree that network caching is the difference, it seems to me that the SLT and Kerel32 request the data in a different manner the later causing the network to cache.

Comment: Caching has been found on data contents, test results have been updated and show a consistency with C#'s File.ReadAllBytes

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting different times it might be because .NET by default uses 4kB buffers for file IO which is 4 times larger than the 1kB buffer your c++ code uses.

EDIT: Bare in mind that since that is a network file, the network latency also adds up to each buffer read. So the smaller the buffer, the more reads, the more added latency and other overhead involved.

EDIT: I've failed to see the entire line of code and missed the extra *1024 piece on the buffer size. So your buffer is actually 1 MB in size. For a fair comparison of the two, use the same buffer size for both c# and c++ implementations.

Comment: The C++ buffer is 1 MiB not 1 KiB

Comment: @CodesInChaos Damn... Didn't scroll properly.

Comment: complete code and test results added into another post